# ID Sci Fi short story: Earth soon to burn in Sun, apartment setting, juice cans, she sleeps, wakes to reality of Earth freezing

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, urban-fantasy, apocalypse, dreams

I could have sworn this was Bradbury. Definitely published pre-1980.  I feel like I should **know** this.

The female (?) protagonist is in an apartment suffering in the heat. 
Earth is moving toward the Sun / the Sun is going Nova. 
She shares one of her last cans of juice with an elderly female neighbor (perhaps named Ruth?)

The heat gets worse and worse. 
In the end, she falls asleep or passes out...and wakes.

She has been in a fever, the events of the story were a dream...but she is sick because of the cold, the bitter cold...because the Earth is moving away from the Sun / the Sun is dying.

I was trying to think of the kind of story where ending in a dream was *not* a cop out.  I wanted this title to use as an example. Now I'm drawing a big blank. Can you help?

Comment: Thanks, all. I feel this is answered. I must have read it in the paperback edition where it was released as a short story.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This was *The Twilight Zone* episode "The Midnight Sun."  Like many original-series *Twilight Zone* episodes, it was penned by Rod Serling.

Norma and her landlady, Mrs. Bronson, are watching and waiting in Norma's apartment as the looming sun heats everything and society breaks down.  Things get worse and worse, until Norma eventually loses consciousness.

When she wakes up, it briefly seems that everything is fine.  It's cold and snowy outside, and Mrs. Bronson and the doctor who has been called in to check on Norma reassure the young woman.  But before he goes, the doctor reveals that the Earth is actually falling away from the sun and freezing; life is just as doomed as it was in Norma's dream.

According to the [*Twilight Zone* Wikia](https://twilightzone.fandom.com/wiki/The_Midnight_Sun):

> In 2008, The Midnight Sun was adapted in a graphic novel of the same name. It was written by Mark Kneece and Rod Sterling and illustrated by Anthony Spay.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good clue. 
I feel very sure I read words on the page; my memory is of print, not images or sounds.  
But Serling used many short stories by Richard Matheson for his work. Like when Matheson's "Disappearing Act" became "And When the Sky was Opened".
I can start looking that way. It could be something similar happened. It's definitely the same story.
Much appreciated.

Comment: @ChrystalHays This story was an original for the show, but see my edit about the graphic novel adaptation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm too old for it to be the graphic novel, but the paperback someone posted is probably it. =)

Answer (score 15):

[image]

The story ["Midnight Sun"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?135140) was adapted in this collection.

You may have seen it with a [different cover](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?39811).

Comment: @ChrystalHays: If this answer helped you, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark below the voting arrows.  This will give both you and the answerer a small amount of rep, and indicate to everyone that the question is resolved.

Comment: Glad to help.  Books like that one were the only way folks could "own" tv episodes back in the dark ages before the advent of home video.